# Can somebody please help me every time i try to compile my document this show up

Tags: pdftex, miktex

This is pdfTeX, Version 3.14159265-2.6-1.40.21 (MiKTeX 20.6 32-bit)

Sorry, but "C:\Program Files\MiKTeX\miktex\bin\miktex-pdftex.exe" did not succeed.

The log file hopefully contains the information to get MiKTeX going again:

C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\MiKTeX\miktex\log\miktex-pdftex.log

FYI i use WINDOWS 10 HOME and MiKTEX

Edited: I include the log file

```
2020-07-01 13:27:55,959+0700 INFO  miktex-pdftex - this process (3748) started by 'miktex-makefmt' with command line: miktex-pdftex.exe --miktex-disable-maintenance --miktex-disable-diagnose --initialize --interaction=nonstopmode --halt-on-error --alias=pdflatex --job-name=pdflatex -tcx=cp227.tcx --enable-etex pdflatex.ini
2020-07-01 13:27:55,981+0700 INFO  miktex-pdftex - allowing known shell commands
2020-07-01 13:27:55,981+0700 INFO  miktex-pdftex - enabling input (output) from (to) processes
2020-07-01 13:28:00,354+0700 INFO  miktex-pdftex - this process (3748) finishes with exit code 1
2020-07-01 13:28:00,354+0700 WARN  miktex.core - still open: "C:/Program Files/MiKTeX/tex/latex/00miktex/pdflatex.ini"
2020-07-01 13:28:00,355+0700 WARN  miktex.core - still open: "C:\Program Files\MiKTeX\tex/latex/base\ltexpl.ltx"
2020-07-01 13:28:00,355+0700 WARN  miktex.core - still open: "C:\Program Files\MiKTeX\tex/latex/l3kernel\expl3.ltx"
2020-07-01 13:28:00,355+0700 WARN  miktex.core - still open: "C:\Program Files\MiKTeX\tex/latex/l3kernel\expl3-code.tex"
2020-07-01 13:28:00,355+0700 WARN  miktex.core - still open: "C:\Program Files\MiKTeX\tex/latex/base\latex.ltx"
2020-07-01 13:30:00,627+0700 INFO  miktex-pdftex - this process (3084) started by 'miktex-makefmt' with command line: miktex-pdftex.exe --miktex-disable-maintenance --miktex-disable-diagnose --initialize --interaction=nonstopmode --halt-on-error --alias=pdflatex --job-name=pdflatex -tcx=cp227.tcx --enable-etex pdflatex.ini
2020-07-01 13:30:00,637+0700 INFO  miktex-pdftex - allowing known shell commands
2020-07-01 13:30:00,637+0700 INFO  miktex-pdftex - enabling input (output) from (to) processes
2020-07-01 13:30:03,610+0700 INFO  miktex-pdftex - this process (3084) finishes with exit code 1
2020-07-01 13:30:03,610+0700 WARN  miktex.core - still open: "C:/Program Files/MiKTeX/tex/latex/00miktex/pdflatex.ini"
2020-07-01 13:30:03,610+0700 WARN  miktex.core - still open: "C:\Program Files\MiKTeX\tex/latex/base\latex.ltx"
2020-07-01 13:30:03,610+0700 WARN  miktex.core - still open: "C:\Program Files\MiKTeX\tex/latex/l3kernel\expl3.ltx"
2020-07-01 13:30:03,610+0700 WARN  miktex.core - still open: "C:\Program Files\MiKTeX\tex/latex/l3kernel\expl3-code.tex"
2020-07-01 13:30:03,611+0700 WARN  miktex.core - still open: "C:\Program Files\MiKTeX\tex/latex/base\ltexpl.ltx"
2020-07-01 13:30:09,275+0700 INFO  miktex-pdftex - this process (1584) started by 'miktex-makefmt' with command line: miktex-pdftex.exe --miktex-disable-maintenance --miktex-disable-diagnose --initialize --interaction=nonstopmode --halt-on-error --job-name=pdftex -tcx=cp227.tcx --enable-etex pdftex.ini
2020-07-01 13:30:09,275+0700 INFO  miktex-pdftex - allowing known shell commands
2020-07-01 13:30:09,275+0700 INFO  miktex-pdftex - enabling input (output) from (to) processes
2020-07-01 13:30:09,798+0700 INFO  miktex-pdftex.core - start process: miktex-maketfm --verbose manfnt
2020-07-01 13:30:12,527+0700 INFO  miktex-pdftex - this process (1584) finishes with exit code 0
2020-07-01 13:30:30,954+0700 INFO  miktex-pdftex - this process (8000) started by 'miktex-makefmt' with command line: miktex-pdftex.exe --miktex-disable-maintenance --miktex-disable-diagnose --initialize --interaction=nonstopmode --halt-on-error --alias=pdflatex --job-name=pdflatex -tcx=cp227.tcx --enable-etex pdflatex.ini
2020-07-01 13:30:30,970+0700 INFO  miktex-pdftex - allowing known shell commands
2020-07-01 13:30:30,970+0700 INFO  miktex-pdftex - enabling input (output) from (to) processes
2020-07-01 13:30:33,999+0700 INFO  miktex-pdftex - this process (8000) finishes with exit code 1
2020-07-01 13:30:33,999+0700 WARN  miktex.core - still open: "C:/Program Files/MiKTeX/tex/latex/00miktex/pdflatex.ini"
2020-07-01 13:30:33,999+0700 WARN  miktex.core - still open: "C:\Program Files\MiKTeX\tex/latex/base\latex.ltx"
2020-07-01 13:30:33,999+0700 WARN  miktex.core - still open: "C:\Program Files\MiKTeX\tex/latex/l3kernel\expl3-code.tex"
2020-07-01 13:30:33,999+0700 WARN  miktex.core - still open: "C:\Program Files\MiKTeX\tex/latex/base\ltexpl.ltx"
2020-07-01 13:30:33,999+0700 WARN  miktex.core - still open: "C:\Program Files\MiKTeX\tex/latex/l3kernel\expl3.ltx"
2020-07-01 13:35:44,730+0700 INFO  miktex-pdftex - this process (7212) started by 'miktex-makefmt' with command line: miktex-pdftex.exe --miktex-disable-maintenance --miktex-disable-diagnose --initialize --interaction=nonstopmode --halt-on-error --alias=pdflatex --job-name=pdflatex -tcx=cp227.tcx --enable-etex pdflatex.ini
2020-07-01 13:35:44,783+0700 INFO  miktex-pdftex - allowing known shell commands
2020-07-01 13:35:44,783+0700 INFO  miktex-pdftex - enabling input (output) from (to) processes
2020-07-01 13:35:48,057+0700 INFO  miktex-pdftex - this process (7212) finishes with exit code 1
2020-07-01 13:35:48,057+0700 WARN  miktex.core - still open: "C:\Program Files\MiKTeX\tex/latex/base\latex.ltx"
2020-07-01 13:35:48,057+0700 WARN  miktex.core - still open: "C:\Program Files\MiKTeX\tex/latex/base\ltexpl.ltx"
2020-07-01 13:35:48,057+0700 WARN  miktex.core - still open: "C:/Program Files/MiKTeX/tex/latex/00miktex/pdflatex.ini"
2020-07-01 13:35:48,057+0700 WARN  miktex.core - still open: "C:\Program Files\MiKTeX\tex/latex/l3kernel\expl3-code.tex"
2020-07-01 13:35:48,057+0700 WARN  miktex.core - still open: "C:\Program Files\MiKTeX\tex/latex/l3kernel\expl3.ltx"
2020-07-01 13:46:52,450+0700 INFO  miktex-pdftex - this process (780) started by 'miktex-makefmt' with command line: miktex-pdftex.exe --miktex-disable-installer --miktex-disable-maintenance --miktex-disable-diagnose --initialize --interaction=nonstopmode --halt-on-error --alias=pdflatex --job-name=pdflatex -tcx=cp227.tcx --enable-etex pdflatex.ini
2020-07-01 13:46:52,458+0700 INFO  miktex-pdftex - allowing known shell commands
2020-07-01 13:46:52,458+0700 INFO  miktex-pdftex - enabling input (output) from (to) processes
2020-07-01 13:46:56,894+0700 INFO  miktex-pdftex - this process (780) finishes with exit code 1
2020-07-01 13:46:56,894+0700 WARN  miktex.core - still open: "C:/Program Files/MiKTeX/tex/latex/00miktex/pdflatex.ini"
2020-07-01 13:46:56,894+0700 WARN  miktex.core - still open: "C:\Program Files\MiKTeX\tex/latex/base\latex.ltx"
2020-07-01 13:46:56,894+0700 WARN  miktex.core - still open: "C:\Program Files\MiKTeX\tex/latex/base\ltexpl.ltx"
2020-07-01 13:46:56,894+0700 WARN  miktex.core - still open: "C:\Program Files\MiKTeX\tex/latex/l3kernel\expl3.ltx"
2020-07-01 13:46:56,894+0700 WARN  miktex.core - still open: "C:\Program Files\MiKTeX\tex/latex/l3kernel\expl3-code.tex"
2020-07-01 13:47:01,046+0700 INFO  miktex-pdftex - this process (3296) started by 'miktex-makefmt' with command line: miktex-pdftex.exe --miktex-disable-installer --miktex-disable-maintenance --miktex-disable-diagnose --initialize --interaction=nonstopmode --halt-on-error --alias=pdflatex --job-name=pdflatex -tcx=cp227.tcx --enable-etex pdflatex.ini
2020-07-01 13:47:01,046+0700 INFO  miktex-pdftex - allowing known shell commands
2020-07-01 13:47:01,046+0700 INFO  miktex-pdftex - enabling input (output) from (to) processes
2020-07-01 13:47:05,187+0700 INFO  miktex-pdftex - this process (3296) finishes with exit code 1
2020-07-01 13:47:05,187+0700 WARN  miktex.core - still open: "C:/Program Files/MiKTeX/tex/latex/00miktex/pdflatex.ini"
2020-07-01 13:47:05,187+0700 WARN  miktex.core - still open: "C:\Program Files\MiKTeX\tex/latex/l3kernel\expl3-code.tex"
2020-07-01 13:47:05,187+0700 WARN  miktex.core - still open: "C:\Program Files\MiKTeX\tex/latex/l3kernel\expl3.ltx"
2020-07-01 13:47:05,188+0700 WARN  miktex.core - still open: "C:\Program Files\MiKTeX\tex/latex/base\ltexpl.ltx"
2020-07-01 13:47:05,188+0700 WARN  miktex.core - still open: "C:\Program Files\MiKTeX\tex/latex/base\latex.ltx"
2020-07-01 13:47:12,218+0700 INFO  miktex-pdftex - this process (396) started by 'miktex-makefmt' with command line: miktex-pdftex.exe --miktex-disable-maintenance --miktex-disable-diagnose --initialize --interaction=nonstopmode --halt-on-error --alias=pdflatex --job-name=pdflatex -tcx=cp227.tcx --enable-etex pdflatex.ini
2020-07-01 13:47:12,231+0700 INFO  miktex-pdftex - allowing known shell commands
2020-07-01 13:47:12,231+0700 INFO  miktex-pdftex - enabling input (output) from (to) processes
2020-07-01 13:47:17,980+0700 INFO  miktex-pdftex - this process (396) finishes with exit code 1
2020-07-01 13:47:17,980+0700 WARN  miktex.core - still open: "C:/Program Files/MiKTeX/tex/latex/00miktex/pdflatex.ini"
2020-07-01 13:47:17,980+0700 WARN  miktex.core - still open: "C:\Program Files\MiKTeX\tex/latex/l3kernel\expl3-code.tex"
2020-07-01 13:47:17,980+0700 WARN  miktex.core - still open: "C:\Program Files\MiKTeX\tex/latex/base\latex.ltx"
2020-07-01 13:47:17,981+0700 WARN  miktex.core - still open: "C:\Program Files\MiKTeX\tex/latex/l3kernel\expl3.ltx"
2020-07-01 13:47:17,981+0700 WARN  miktex.core - still open: "C:\Program Files\MiKTeX\tex/latex/base\ltexpl.ltx"
2020-07-01 13:47:18,406+0700 INFO  miktex-pdftex - this process (3692) started by 'miktex-makefmt' with command line: miktex-pdftex.exe --miktex-disable-installer --miktex-disable-maintenance --miktex-disable-diagnose --initialize --interaction=nonstopmode --halt-on-error --alias=pdflatex --job-name=pdflatex -tcx=cp227.tcx --enable-etex pdflatex.ini
2020-07-01 13:47:18,415+0700 INFO  miktex-pdftex - allowing known shell commands
2020-07-01 13:47:18,415+0700 INFO  miktex-pdftex - enabling input (output) from (to) processes
2020-07-01 13:47:21,880+0700 INFO  miktex-pdftex - this process (3692) finishes with exit code 1
2020-07-01 13:47:21,880+0700 WARN  miktex.core - still open: "C:/Program Files/MiKTeX/tex/latex/00miktex/pdflatex.ini"
2020-07-01 13:47:21,880+0700 WARN  miktex.core - still open: "C:\Program Files\MiKTeX\tex/latex/l3kernel\expl3-code.tex"
2020-07-01 13:47:21,880+0700 WARN  miktex.core - still open: "C:\Program Files\MiKTeX\tex/latex/base\latex.ltx"
2020-07-01 13:47:21,880+0700 WARN  miktex.core - still open: "C:\Program Files\MiKTeX\tex/latex/l3kernel\expl3.ltx"
2020-07-01 13:47:21,880+0700 WARN  miktex.core - still open: "C:\Program Files\MiKTeX\tex/latex/base\ltexpl.ltx"
2020-07-01 13:47:23,881+0700 INFO  miktex-pdftex - this process (2096) started by 'miktex-makefmt' with command line: miktex-pdftex.exe --miktex-disable-installer --miktex-disable-maintenance --miktex-disable-diagnose --initialize --interaction=nonstopmode --halt-on-error --alias=pdflatex --job-name=pdflatex -tcx=cp227.tcx --enable-etex pdflatex.ini
2020-07-01 13:47:23,890+0700 INFO  miktex-pdftex - allowing known shell commands
2020-07-01 13:47:23,890+0700 INFO  miktex-pdftex - enabling input (output) from (to) processes
2020-07-01 13:47:27,131+0700 INFO  miktex-pdftex - this process (2096) finishes with exit code 1
2020-07-01 13:47:27,131+0700 WARN  miktex.core - still open: "C:/Program Files/MiKTeX/tex/latex/00miktex/pdflatex.ini"
2020-07-01 13:47:27,131+0700 WARN  miktex.core - still open: "C:\Program Files\MiKTeX\tex/latex/l3kernel\expl3.ltx"
2020-07-01 13:47:27,131+0700 WARN  miktex.core - still open: "C:\Program Files\MiKTeX\tex/latex/base\latex.ltx"
2020-07-01 13:47:27,131+0700 WARN  miktex.core - still open: "C:\Program Files\MiKTeX\tex/latex/base\ltexpl.ltx"
2020-07-01 13:47:27,131+0700 WARN  miktex.core - still open: "C:\Program Files\MiKTeX\tex/latex/l3kernel\expl3-code.tex"
2020-07-01 13:48:05,209+0700 INFO  miktex-pdftex - this process (1848) started by 'miktex-makefmt' with command line: miktex-pdftex.exe --miktex-disable-maintenance --miktex-disable-diagnose --initialize --interaction=nonstopmode --halt-on-error --alias=pdflatex --job-name=pdflatex -tcx=cp227.tcx --enable-etex pdflatex.ini
2020-07-01 13:48:05,219+0700 INFO  miktex-pdftex - allowing known shell commands
2020-07-01 13:48:05,219+0700 INFO  miktex-pdftex - enabling input (output) from (to) processes
2020-07-01 13:48:08,538+0700 INFO  miktex-pdftex - this process (1848) finishes with exit code 1
2020-07-01 13:48:08,538+0700 WARN  miktex.core - still open: "C:/Program Files/MiKTeX/tex/latex/00miktex/pdflatex.ini"
2020-07-01 13:48:08,538+0700 WARN  miktex.core - still open: "C:\Program Files\MiKTeX\tex/latex/base\latex.ltx"
2020-07-01 13:48:08,538+0700 WARN  miktex.core - still open: "C:\Program Files\MiKTeX\tex/latex/l3kernel\expl3.ltx"
2020-07-01 13:48:08,538+0700 WARN  miktex.core - still open: "C:\Program Files\MiKTeX\tex/latex/base\ltexpl.ltx"
2020-07-01 13:48:08,539+0700 WARN  miktex.core - still open: "C:\Program Files\MiKTeX\tex/latex/l3kernel\expl3-code.tex"
2020-07-01 13:48:21,980+0700 INFO  miktex-pdftex - this process (5652) started by 'miktex-makefmt' with command line: miktex-pdftex.exe --miktex-disable-maintenance --miktex-disable-diagnose --initialize --interaction=nonstopmode --halt-on-error --alias=pdflatex --job-name=pdflatex -tcx=cp227.tcx --enable-etex pdflatex.ini
2020-07-01 13:48:21,989+0700 INFO  miktex-pdftex - allowing known shell commands
2020-07-01 13:48:21,989+0700 INFO  miktex-pdftex - enabling input (output) from (to) processes
2020-07-01 13:48:25,194+0700 INFO  miktex-pdftex - this process (5652) finishes with exit code 1
2020-07-01 13:48:25,194+0700 WARN  miktex.core - still open: "C:/Program Files/MiKTeX/tex/latex/00miktex/pdflatex.ini"
2020-07-01 13:48:25,195+0700 WARN  miktex.core - still open: "C:\Program Files\MiKTeX\tex/latex/base\latex.ltx"
2020-07-01 13:48:25,195+0700 WARN  miktex.core - still open: "C:\Program Files\MiKTeX\tex/latex/base\ltexpl.ltx"
2020-07-01 13:48:25,195+0700 WARN  miktex.core - still open: "C:\Program Files\MiKTeX\tex/latex/l3kernel\expl3-code.tex"
2020-07-01 13:48:25,195+0700 WARN  miktex.core - still open: "C:\Program Files\MiKTeX\tex/latex/l3kernel\expl3.ltx"
2020-07-01 13:49:09,887+0700 INFO  miktex-pdftex - this process (7012) started by 'miktex-makefmt' with command line: miktex-pdftex.exe --miktex-disable-maintenance --miktex-disable-diagnose --initialize --interaction=nonstopmode --halt-on-error --alias=pdflatex --job-name=pdflatex -tcx=cp227.tcx --enable-etex pdflatex.ini
2020-07-01 13:49:09,903+0700 INFO  miktex-pdftex - allowing known shell commands
2020-07-01 13:49:09,903+0700 INFO  miktex-pdftex - enabling input (output) from (to) processes
2020-07-01 13:49:13,266+0700 INFO  miktex-pdftex - this process (7012) finishes with exit code 1
2020-07-01 13:49:13,266+0700 WARN  miktex.core - still open: "C:/Program Files/MiKTeX/tex/latex/00miktex/pdflatex.ini"
2020-07-01 13:49:13,266+0700 WARN  miktex.core - still open: "C:\Program Files\MiKTeX\tex/latex/base\ltexpl.ltx"
2020-07-01 13:49:13,266+0700 WARN  miktex.core - still open: "C:\Program Files\MiKTeX\tex/latex/l3kernel\expl3.ltx"
2020-07-01 13:49:13,266+0700 WARN  miktex.core - still open: "C:\Program Files\MiKTeX\tex/latex/l3kernel\expl3-code.tex"
2020-07-01 13:49:13,266+0700 WARN  miktex.core - still open: "C:\Program Files\MiKTeX\tex/latex/base\latex.ltx"
2020-07-01 13:50:00,203+0700 INFO  miktex-pdftex - this process (3432) started by 'miktex-makefmt' with command line: miktex-pdftex.exe --miktex-disable-maintenance --miktex-disable-diagnose --initialize --interaction=nonstopmode --halt-on-error --alias=pdflatex --job-name=pdflatex -tcx=cp227.tcx --enable-etex pdflatex.ini
2020-07-01 13:50:00,212+0700 INFO  miktex-pdftex - allowing known shell commands
2020-07-01 13:50:00,212+0700 INFO  miktex-pdftex - enabling input (output) from (to) processes
2020-07-01 13:50:03,626+0700 INFO  miktex-pdftex - this process (3432) finishes with exit code 1
2020-07-01 13:50:03,627+0700 WARN  miktex.core - still open: "C:\Program Files\MiKTeX\tex/latex/l3kernel\expl3-code.tex"
2020-07-01 13:50:03,627+0700 WARN  miktex.core - still open: "C:\Program Files\MiKTeX\tex/latex/base\latex.ltx"
2020-07-01 13:50:03,627+0700 WARN  miktex.core - still open: "C:\Program Files\MiKTeX\tex/latex/l3kernel\expl3.ltx"
2020-07-01 13:50:03,627+0700 WARN  miktex.core - still open: "C:\Program Files\MiKTeX\tex/latex/base\ltexpl.ltx"
2020-07-01 13:50:03,627+0700 WARN  miktex.core - still open: "C:/Program Files/MiKTeX/tex/latex/00miktex/pdflatex.ini"
2020-07-01 15:16:18,935+0700 INFO  miktex-pdftex - this process (1020) started by 'miktex-makefmt' with command line: miktex-pdftex.exe --miktex-disable-maintenance --miktex-disable-diagnose --initialize --interaction=nonstopmode --halt-on-error --alias=pdflatex --job-name=pdflatex -tcx=cp227.tcx --enable-etex pdflatex.ini
2020-07-01 15:16:18,950+0700 INFO  miktex-pdftex - allowing known shell commands
2020-07-01 15:16:18,950+0700 INFO  miktex-pdftex - enabling input (output) from (to) processes
2020-07-01 15:16:23,228+0700 INFO  miktex-pdftex - this process (1020) finishes with exit code 1
2020-07-01 15:16:23,228+0700 WARN  miktex.core - still open: "C:/Program Files/MiKTeX/tex/latex/00miktex/pdflatex.ini"
2020-07-01 15:16:23,228+0700 WARN  miktex.core - still open: "C:\Program Files\MiKTeX\tex/latex/l3kernel\expl3-code.tex"
2020-07-01 15:16:23,228+0700 WARN  miktex.core - still open: "C:\Program Files\MiKTeX\tex/latex/l3kernel\expl3.ltx"
2020-07-01 15:16:23,228+0700 WARN  miktex.core - still open: "C:\Program Files\MiKTeX\tex/latex/base\latex.ltx"
2020-07-01 15:16:23,228+0700 WARN  miktex.core - still open: "C:\Program Files\MiKTeX\tex/latex/base\ltexpl.ltx"
2020-07-01 15:28:56,130+0700 INFO  miktex-pdftex - this process (4172) started by 'miktex-makefmt' with command line: miktex-pdftex.exe --miktex-disable-maintenance --miktex-disable-diagnose --initialize --interaction=nonstopmode --halt-on-error --alias=pdflatex --job-name=pdflatex -tcx=cp227.tcx --enable-etex pdflatex.ini
2020-07-01 15:28:56,231+0700 INFO  miktex-pdftex - allowing known shell commands
2020-07-01 15:28:56,231+0700 INFO  miktex-pdftex - enabling input (output) from (to) processes
2020-07-01 15:29:00,717+0700 INFO  miktex-pdftex - this process (4172) finishes with exit code 1
2020-07-01 15:29:00,717+0700 WARN  miktex.core - still open: "C:/Program Files/MiKTeX/tex/latex/00miktex/pdflatex.ini"
2020-07-01 15:29:00,717+0700 WARN  miktex.core - still open: "C:\Program Files\MiKTeX\tex/latex/base\latex.ltx"
2020-07-01 15:29:00,717+0700 WARN  miktex.core - still open: "C:\Program Files\MiKTeX\tex/latex/l3kernel\expl3.ltx"
2020-07-01 15:29:00,717+0700 WARN  miktex.core - still open: "C:\Program Files\MiKTeX\tex/latex/l3kernel\expl3-code.tex"
2020-07-01 15:29:00,717+0700 WARN  miktex.core - still open: "C:\Program Files\MiKTeX\tex/latex/base\ltexpl.ltx"
2020-07-01 15:31:29,473+0700 INFO  miktex-pdftex - this process (4052) started by 'miktex-makefmt' with command line: miktex-pdftex.exe --miktex-disable-maintenance --miktex-disable-diagnose --initialize --interaction=nonstopmode --halt-on-error --alias=pdflatex --job-name=pdflatex -tcx=cp227.tcx --enable-etex pdflatex.ini
2020-07-01 15:31:29,484+0700 INFO  miktex-pdftex - allowing known shell commands
2020-07-01 15:31:29,484+0700 INFO  miktex-pdftex - enabling input (output) from (to) processes
2020-07-01 15:31:35,771+0700 INFO  miktex-pdftex - this process (4052) finishes with exit code 1
2020-07-01 15:31:35,771+0700 WARN  miktex.core - still open: "C:/Program Files/MiKTeX/tex/latex/00miktex/pdflatex.ini"
2020-07-01 15:31:35,771+0700 WARN  miktex.core - still open: "C:\Program Files\MiKTeX\tex/latex/l3kernel\expl3.ltx"
2020-07-01 15:31:35,771+0700 WARN  miktex.core - still open: "C:\Program Files\MiKTeX\tex/latex/base\ltexpl.ltx"
2020-07-01 15:31:35,771+0700 WARN  miktex.core - still open: "C:\Program Files\MiKTeX\tex/latex/base\latex.ltx"
2020-07-01 15:31:35,771+0700 WARN  miktex.core - still open: "C:\Program Files\MiKTeX\tex/latex/l3kernel\expl3-code.tex"
2020-07-01 15:33:42,031+0700 INFO  miktex-pdftex - this process (5384) started by 'miktex-makefmt' with command line: miktex-pdftex.exe --miktex-disable-maintenance --miktex-disable-diagnose --initialize --interaction=nonstopmode --halt-on-error --alias=pdflatex --job-name=pdflatex -tcx=cp227.tcx --enable-etex pdflatex.ini
2020-07-01 15:33:42,031+0700 INFO  miktex-pdftex - allowing known shell commands
2020-07-01 15:33:42,031+0700 INFO  miktex-pdftex - enabling input (output) from (to) processes
2020-07-01 15:33:47,029+0700 INFO  miktex-pdftex - this process (5384) finishes with exit code 1
2020-07-01 15:33:47,029+0700 WARN  miktex.core - still open: "C:/Program Files/MiKTeX/tex/latex/00miktex/pdflatex.ini"
2020-07-01 15:33:47,030+0700 WARN  miktex.core - still open: "C:\Program Files\MiKTeX\tex/latex/l3kernel\expl3-code.tex"
2020-07-01 15:33:47,030+0700 WARN  miktex.core - still open: "C:\Program Files\MiKTeX\tex/latex/base\latex.ltx"
2020-07-01 15:33:47,030+0700 WARN  miktex.core - still open: "C:\Program Files\MiKTeX\tex/latex/base\ltexpl.ltx"
2020-07-01 15:33:47,030+0700 WARN  miktex.core - still open: "C:\Program Files\MiKTeX\tex/latex/l3kernel\expl3.ltx"
2020-07-01 15:50:55,144+0700 INFO  miktex-pdftex - this process (5000) started by 'miktex-makefmt' with command line: miktex-pdftex.exe --miktex-enable-installer --miktex-disable-maintenance --miktex-disable-diagnose --initialize --interaction=nonstopmode --halt-on-error --alias=pdflatex --job-name=pdflatex -tcx=cp227.tcx --enable-etex pdflatex.ini
2020-07-01 15:50:55,160+0700 INFO  miktex-pdftex - allowing known shell commands
2020-07-01 15:50:55,160+0700 INFO  miktex-pdftex - enabling input (output) from (to) processes
2020-07-01 15:51:00,026+0700 INFO  miktex-pdftex - this process (5000) finishes with exit code 1
2020-07-01 15:51:00,026+0700 WARN  miktex.core - still open: "C:/Program Files/MiKTeX/tex/latex/00miktex/pdflatex.ini"
2020-07-01 15:51:00,026+0700 WARN  miktex.core - still open: "C:\Program Files\MiKTeX\tex/latex/l3kernel\expl3-code.tex"
2020-07-01 15:51:00,027+0700 WARN  miktex.core - still open: "C:\Program Files\MiKTeX\tex/latex/base\latex.ltx"
2020-07-01 15:51:00,027+0700 WARN  miktex.core - still open: "C:\Program Files\MiKTeX\tex/latex/base\ltexpl.ltx"
2020-07-01 15:51:00,027+0700 WARN  miktex.core - still open: "C:\Program Files\MiKTeX\tex/latex/l3kernel\expl3.ltx"
2020-07-01 15:51:57,484+0700 INFO  miktex-pdftex - this process (5132) started by 'miktex-makefmt' with command line: miktex-pdftex.exe --miktex-enable-installer --miktex-disable-maintenance --miktex-disable-diagnose --initialize --interaction=nonstopmode --halt-on-error --alias=pdflatex --job-name=pdflatex -tcx=cp227.tcx --enable-etex pdflatex.ini
2020-07-01 15:51:57,500+0700 INFO  miktex-pdftex - allowing known shell commands
2020-07-01 15:51:57,500+0700 INFO  miktex-pdftex - enabling input (output) from (to) processes
2020-07-01 15:52:02,610+0700 INFO  miktex-pdftex - this process (5132) finishes with exit code 1
2020-07-01 15:52:02,611+0700 WARN  miktex.core - still open: "C:/Program Files/MiKTeX/tex/latex/00miktex/pdflatex.ini"
2020-07-01 15:52:02,611+0700 WARN  miktex.core - still open: "C:\Program Files\MiKTeX\tex/latex/l3kernel\expl3.ltx"
2020-07-01 15:52:02,611+0700 WARN  miktex.core - still open: "C:\Program Files\MiKTeX\tex/latex/base\latex.ltx"
2020-07-01 15:52:02,611+0700 WARN  miktex.core - still open: "C:\Program Files\MiKTeX\tex/latex/l3kernel\expl3-code.tex"
2020-07-01 15:52:02,611+0700 WARN  miktex.core - still open: "C:\Program Files\MiKTeX\tex/latex/base\ltexpl.ltx"
2020-07-01 15:56:08,820+0700 INFO  miktex-pdftex - this process (304) started by 'miktex-makefmt' with command line: miktex-pdftex.exe --miktex-enable-installer --miktex-disable-maintenance --miktex-disable-diagnose --initialize --interaction=nonstopmode --halt-on-error --job-name=pdftex -tcx=cp227.tcx --enable-etex pdftex.ini
2020-07-01 15:56:08,822+0700 INFO  miktex-pdftex - allowing known shell commands
2020-07-01 15:56:08,822+0700 INFO  miktex-pdftex - enabling input (output) from (to) processes
2020-07-01 15:56:09,687+0700 INFO  miktex-pdftex - this process (304) finishes with exit code 0
2020-07-02 17:02:41,518+0700 INFO  miktex-pdftex - this process (1080) started by 'miktex-texworks' with command line: "C:\Program Files\MiKTeX\miktex\bin\miktex-pdftex.exe" -synctex=1 -undump=pdflatex "tugas minat polinomial.tex"
2020-07-02 17:02:41,569+0700 INFO  miktex-pdftex - allowing known shell commands
2020-07-02 17:02:41,569+0700 INFO  miktex-pdftex - enabling input (output) from (to) processes
2020-07-02 17:02:41,655+0700 INFO  miktex-pdftex - going to create file: pdflatex.fmt
2020-07-02 17:02:41,701+0700 INFO  miktex-pdftex.core - start process: initexmf --dump-by-name=pdflatex --engine=pdftex
2020-07-02 17:02:43,013+0700 INFO  miktex-pdftex - this process (3060) started by 'miktex-makefmt' with command line: miktex-pdftex.exe --miktex-disable-maintenance --miktex-disable-diagnose --initialize --interaction=nonstopmode --halt-on-error --alias=pdflatex --job-name=pdflatex -tcx=cp227.tcx --enable-etex pdflatex.ini
2020-07-02 17:02:43,022+0700 INFO  miktex-pdftex - allowing known shell commands
2020-07-02 17:02:43,022+0700 INFO  miktex-pdftex - enabling input (output) from (to) processes
2020-07-02 17:02:48,522+0700 INFO  miktex-pdftex - this process (3060) finishes with exit code 1
2020-07-02 17:02:48,522+0700 WARN  miktex.core - still open: "C:/Program Files/MiKTeX/tex/latex/00miktex/pdflatex.ini"
2020-07-02 17:02:48,522+0700 WARN  miktex.core - still open: "C:\Program Files\MiKTeX\tex/latex/base\ltexpl.ltx"
2020-07-02 17:02:48,522+0700 WARN  miktex.core - still open: "C:\Program Files\MiKTeX\tex/latex/base\latex.ltx"
2020-07-02 17:02:48,522+0700 WARN  miktex.core - still open: "C:\Program Files\MiKTeX\tex/latex/l3kernel\expl3.ltx"
2020-07-02 17:02:48,522+0700 WARN  miktex.core - still open: "C:\Program Files\MiKTeX\tex/latex/l3kernel\expl3-code.tex"
2020-07-02 17:02:48,612+0700 ERROR miktex-pdftex - C:\Program Files\MiKTeX\miktex\bin\initexmf.exe did not succeed; exitCode: 1
2020-07-02 17:02:48,612+0700 ERROR miktex-pdftex - output:
2020-07-02 17:02:48,612+0700 ERROR miktex-pdftex - 
Sorry, but "MiKTeX Configuration Utility" did not succeed.

The log file hopefully contains the information to get MiKTeX going again:

  C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\MiKTeX\miktex\log\initexmf.log

2020-07-02 17:02:48,612+0700 FATAL miktex-pdftex.core - The memory dump file could not be found.
2020-07-02 17:02:48,612+0700 FATAL miktex-pdftex.core - Data: fileName="pdflatex.fmt"
2020-07-02 17:02:48,612+0700 FATAL miktex-pdftex.core - Source: Libraries\MiKTeX\TeXAndFriends\texmfapp.cpp:708
2020-07-02 17:02:48,612+0700 FATAL miktex-pdftex - The memory dump file could not be found.
2020-07-02 17:02:48,612+0700 FATAL miktex-pdftex - Info: fileName="pdflatex.fmt"
2020-07-02 17:02:48,612+0700 FATAL miktex-pdftex - Source: Libraries\MiKTeX\TeXAndFriends\texmfapp.cpp
2020-07-02 17:02:48,613+0700 FATAL miktex-pdftex - Line: 708
2020-07-02 17:02:48,613+0700 INFO  miktex-pdftex - this process (1080) finishes with exit code 1
```

and i dont know what to do with it

Comment: So what is the contents of the log file?

Comment: i already edit my question @Marijn

Comment: MiKTeX not able to create the format file `pdflatex.fmt`. Run this command and see what happens: `miktex-pdftex --ini  --alias=pdflatex --job-name=pdflatex -tcx=cp227.tcx --enable-etex pdflatex.ini`

Comment: LaTeX3 Error: File 'UnicodeData.txt' not found.

For immediate help type H <return>.
 ...

l.28193   }


! LaTeX3 Error: File 'l3deprecation.def' not found.

For immediate help type H <return>.
 ...

l.31226 ..._configuration_load:n { l3deprecation }

)))
 ) )
(\end occurred inside a group at level 1)

### semi simple group (level 1) entered at line 31211 (\begingroup)
### bottom level
! You can't dump inside a group.
<*> ...les/MiKTeX/tex/latex/00miktex/pdflatex.ini"

!  ==> Fatal error occurred, no output PDF file produced!
Transcript written on pdflatex.log.

Comment: @ChristianSchenk i already run it then the cmd show this

Comment: Had the same problem with the new update. Replaced the file pdflatex.exe with the old one (2.9.7442) and worked.